# Connection refused by Drone IO

Tags: drone.io, gogs

Im trying to integrate a self-hosted drone server into my gogs service.

i startet my docker container with this command

```
    sudo docker run -e DRONE_GOGS=true -e DRONE_GOGS_URL=https://my-url DRONE_OPEN=true DRONE_ADMIN=admin -e DRONE_SECRET=somesecret123 -v /var/lib/drone:/var/lib/drone -p 80:8000 --restart=always --name=drone drone/drone
```

But when i try to access via webbrowser iam recieving an `Connection Refused` Error.

I have been reading about a `docker-compose.yaml` which has to be created...
But where do i have to create this File?

Thank you very much

Comment: `docker-compose` is different to docker, in that it's used to describe a collection of many `docker` containers, e.g. a DB, API, and UI (three separate containers working together as a single service).
If your "DRONE_GOGS" is a single container you can stick with plain old `docker`... If there's nothing useful in the logs I would try "exec-ing" into the _running_ container and having a look... `docker exec -ti drone sh` - from there you should be able to get more information...

Comment: Now I look more closely at your command, I can see the you've missed a couple of `-e` from your environment variable declarations -
 in the above: `DRONE_OPEN=true DRONE_ADMIN=admin` should be `-e DRONE_OPEN=true -e DRONE_ADMIN=admin`, that might help.